# as_json with :except not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to format a json response removing unwanted fields for a smaller response (i.e. created_at and updated_at)

I'm currently doing this:

```
friends = @user.friends
friends.each do |f|
  f[:name] = f.user.username # adding arbitrary attribute needed in the response
end
render :json => friends.as_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at])
```

created_at and updated_at are still included in the response, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:except` won't handle attributes nested in your array. you can use it on the instances themselves:

```
friends = @user.friends.map do |f|
  f[:name] = f.user.username # adding arbitrary attribute needed in the response
  f.as_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
end
render :json => friends
```

Comment: that makes sense, thanks phoet!  I ended up going this route `@user.fiends.as_json(:methods => :name, :except => [:created_at, :updated_at])`